How to Set Up Hot Reload for Gin Application Using Docker and Air in Dev Environment?
I'm working on a backend system using Gin and Docker, and I'm trying to set up two different environments: development and production. In the development environment, I want to use Air for hot reloading.
Here are the relevant files and configurations I'm using:
.air.toml
# Working directory
root = "."
tmp_dir = "tmp"

[build]
cmd = "go build -o ./tmp/main ."
bin = "tmp/main"
full_bin = "APP_ENV=dev APP_USER=air ./tmp/main"
include_ext = ["go", "tpl", "tmpl", "html"]
exclude_dir = ["assets", "tmp", "vendor", "frontend/node_modules"]
include_dir = []
exclude_file = []
delay = 1000 # ms
stop_on_error = true
log = "air_errors.log"

[log]
time = false

[color]
main = "magenta"
watcher = "cyan"
build = "yellow"
runner = "green"

[misc]
clean_on_exit = true


Dockerfile:
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.3

# Base stage for building the Go application
FROM golang:1.22.5-alpine AS base

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go build -o main .

# Development stage
FROM base AS dev

RUN apk add --no-cache git \
    && go install github.com/air-verse/air@latest

COPY .air.toml ./
CMD ["air"]

# Production stage
FROM alpine:latest AS prod

WORKDIR /root/

COPY --from=base /app/main .

CMD ["./main"]

docker-compose.yml:
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_password_here
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      target: ${BUILD_STAGE:-prod}
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}
      JWT_SECRET_KEY: ${JWT_SECRET_KEY}
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  db_data:


Issue:
When I try to run my application in development mode usingdocker-compose --env-file .env.development up --build Docker Compose, Air doesn't seem to be triggering hot reloads as expected. The application builds and runs, but changes to the Go files don't result in a rebuild and restart.
What I've tried:

Verified that Air is installed correctly in the dev stage of the Dockerfile.
Checked the .air.toml configuration to ensure it is set up correctly for hot reloading.
Ensured that the Docker Compose file is using the dev target for the app service.

Expected behavior:
When running docker-compose up, I expect that any changes to my Go source files should trigger Air to rebuild and restart the application automatically.
Actual behavior:
Changes to Go source files do not trigger Air to rebuild and restart the application. I have to manually rebuild and restart the container to see changes (which I want this behaviour to be only applicable on prod env).
How can I properly configure my setup to enable hot reloading with Air in the development environment when using Docker and Docker Compose?

Not sure, but according to this link I guess you may have to map port 3000 to your container too. So - 8080:8080    - 3000:3000

I'd do my local development using a local Go installation.  You can docker-compose up -d db to get a containerized database.  The container can't normally see the source code on the host machine (and a Go application won't normally have its source code in the container at all), and it makes things harder if the go tool is hidden inside a container where you can't directly run it.
